# Why I cannot initialize radiobutton in a group?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I have two radio buttons:

however, altough they have the same group name and I set one of them "checked" when I load my page they both look unchecked.

I even tried to set them on the code behind but still the check is not reflected to UI.

What do I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: please post the snippet of the radio button group code

Comment: Here it is:

<asp:RadioButton ID="chbYesToOpen" runat="server" GroupName="ChangeToOpen" Text="Yes" Checked="false" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="chbNoToOpen" runat="server" GroupName="ChangeToOpen" Text="No" Checked="true" />

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="chbYesToOpen" runat="server" GroupName="ChangeToOpen" Text="Yes" Checked="false" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="chbNoToOpen" runat="server" GroupName="ChangeToOpen" Text="No" Checked="true" />
```

Is the code you are ustrying the following?:

```
chbYesToOpen.Checked = true;
```

Well I think this is the problem because you can't have 2 of them set as true.  So try clearing the one that is set to true first and then setting the one you wanted checked after:

```
chbNoToOpen.Checked = false;
chbYesToOpen.Checked = true;
```

Or make sure in your markup, they are both set to `Checked="false"` by default and you should be ok to just set one to false.

**Edit:** I just tested your exact scenario and was able to recreate it and the solution I mentioned will fix your issue.

Comment: @burak ozdogan just following up, did you ever get this figured out?